# How does RCSB determine the origin of the Cartesian coordinate system utilized in all PDB files

Tags: protein-structure, pdb, 3d-structure

When perusing through the text version of a PDB file, I noticed in records that begin with "ATOM," there are x, y, and z coordinates for these atoms.
How is the origin of each molecule's Cartesian coordinate system determined by RCSB?

Comment: They are just arbitrary numbers, the only thing which matters are the relative coordinates. The relative coordinates themselves are determined mostly by X-ray crystallography or NMR.